# Convert a dataframe column to timestamp format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column `'time'`  in format `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM'`

How can I convert the entire column values to the format: `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+01:00'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+01:00')
```

Result:

```
0    2023-07-01 10:30:00+01:00
```